# Why does clang say _Imaginary_I is not declared?

Tags: c, complex-numbers

Running

```
clang test.c -o test
```

On this file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main()
{
    _Complex double z = 1.0 + _Imaginary_I * 2.0;
    return 0;
}
```

fails to compile because of

```
error: use of undeclared identifier '_Imaginary_I'.
```

According to [onlinepubs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/complex.h.html), `_Imaginary_I` is defined.  What happened?

Comment: Also `double _Complex z = 1.0 + _Imaginary_I*2.0` doesn't work.

Comment: Compile with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` flags; some compilers default to C89 mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imaginary numbers, and `_Imaginary_I`, are optional features in the C Standard.

Complex numbers are also an optional feature as of C11, but are commonly supported by implementations. `I` and `_Complex_I` should work instead.

---

According to the standard, you should be able to test for conformance at compile-time by checking the values of the following macros:

- `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__`: value `1` means that complex and imaginary types exist and comply with IEC 60559.
- `__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__`: value `1` means that neither complex nor imaginary types exist.

However in practice this is not reliable, e.g. [gcc defines the macro without supporting the feature](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15720).

Comment: Yes, it worked;  one other silly question:  is declaration with `_Complex double` equivalent to `double _Complex`?  They both seem to compile.  (**Edit**: actually, `_Compile double` doesn't work with `<complex.h>` functions.  Apparently, it is a valid type, just not compatible with `<complex.h>`).

Comment: @QuantumDot `double _Complex` is the usual ordering, however it should be exactly equivalent to use `_Complex double`

Comment: @QuantumDot: `_Compile` != `_Complex` could be the problem. ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, if I remember correctly, gcc+glibc environments define `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` (Annex G conformance claim) despite not having `_Imaginary`, which is the main interesting property the macro is supposed to imply...

Comment: @R.. How unfortunate. I found a bug report thread and updated my answer