# How to enter complex number in an expression in C++

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

In C, I am able to use complex numbers inside of an expression using `CMPLX`:

```
#include <complex.h>

int main(){

    double _Complex result;
    //complicated code
    result = ((3.1*CMPLX(0.,1.))+2.);

return 0;
}
```

How do I do the same in C++?

```
#include <complex>

int main(){

    std::complex<double> result;
    //complicated code
    result = ((3.1*???(0.,1.))+2.);   // what to put in '???'

return 0;
}
```

Is there something short I can put in for `???`?  I don't want to write it with a `+` operation:  `0.0 + 1.0 I`.

Comment: Can't you just use the original C <complex.h> instead of <complex>. Not sure if that's good practice though

Comment: @ElijahSeedArita Thanks, I want to do it right since I will be sharing my code with bunch of people who will build on it.

Comment: One would expect `std::complex<double>`.

Comment: Why did you write `(3.1*CMPLX(0.,1.))+2.` instead of `CMPLX(2., 3.1)`

Comment: Also it is unclear why you're happy with `(3.1*CMPLX(0.,1.))+2.`, but not happy with `3.1*I + 2.`

Comment: @M.M It may be my misunderstanding, but I thought `CMPLX(2.1.,3.1)` compiles and runs faster than `2.1 + 3.1 I`.

Comment: @QuantumDot `CMPLX` is a macro which expands to exactly that . E.g. (from the C standard) `#define CMPLX(x, y) ((double complex)((double)(x) + 
_Imaginary_I * (double)(y)))`

Comment: @M.M uh oh.  That means I have it all backwards!  So do I understand that the most efficient way to go is really `a + _Imaginary_I * b`?  How bizarre!  I thought that complex numbers are implemented as an array of 2 elements, so the most efficient thing to do was to use them in as close as possible way to their implementation: an array of two elements, and not a binary operation!

Comment: @M.M But wait!  I can't compile it like that.  `_Imaginary_I` doesn't compile for me (see my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45002381/1949370)).  What's going on!?  What is the *correct* way to make this *as efficient* and *as portable* as possible?

Comment: @QuantumDot `_Imaginary_I` is optional and the standard says that `CMPLX` should behave as if it were defined by that macro where the compiler also does implement `_Imaginary_I`. You could try `_Complex_I` instead, or look up the contents of the `complex.h` header on your system

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would be to use [user defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) to create a `complex` literal

```
#include<complex>
using namespace std::literals;

auto result = (3.1 * 1if) + 2;
```

Or if you don't have C++14, calling the constructor of a class will create a temporary

```
auto result = (3.1 * std::complex<double>{0, 1}) + 2;
```

Comment: Ok, sounds good; I can't use C++14.  But do you mean `std::complex<double>(0, 1)`, with parenthesis and `std::` prefix?  It seems awful long to type that.  I wonder why they made it so long.  It was much nicer in Fortran (`DCMPLX`) and C (`CMPLX`).

Comment: @QuantumDot Yeah the `std::`, but the curly braces are deliberate although unnecessary. The reason its long is to avoid name collisions. If you only ever use `std::complex<double>`, you can alias it `using complex = std::complex<double>`

Comment: But it's not compiling with curly braces.  clang gives this error: `error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`.  Are you sure?  (Also, the final `2` should be `2.`, right?)

Comment: @QuantumDot You need C++11 for this. `(` works just fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a *type alias* to make the `std::complex` type easier to use.

For example:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

// create a type alias
using CMPLX = std::complex<double>;

int main()
{
    // use it the same way you did in `C`
    auto result = ((3.1 * CMPLX(0.0, 1.0)) + 2.0);

    std::cout << "result: " << result << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
result: (2,3.1)
```

Comment: Ok, very good.  Is the type alias restricted to this one file?

Comment: @QuantumDot If you have a multi-file project then put the type alias in a *header file* and `#include` it wherever you need it.